# AutoML for categorical feature encoding

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, automl, h2o

I have an input dataset with more than 100 variables where around 80% of the variables are categorical in nature.

While some variables like gender, country etc can be one-hot encoded but I also have few variables which have an inherent order in their values such rating - Very good, good, bad etc.

Is there any auto-ML approach which we can use to do this encoding based on the variable type?

For ex: I would like to provide the below two lists as input to the auto-ml arguments.

```
one-hot-list = ['Gender', 'Country']  # one-hot encoding
ordinal_list = ['Feedback', 'Level_of_interest'] # ordinal encoding
```

Is there any auto-ML package that can do this for us?

Or is there any other efficient way to do this as I have 80 categorical columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, there are plenty of them, using `scikit-learn` it will looks as follow:

```
from  sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, OrdinalEncoder

ohe = OneHotEncoder()
ordine = OrdinalEncoder()

oh_col_names = [...]
ordin_col_names = [...]

encoded_oh = ohe.fit_transform(X[oh_col_names]) # supposing X is your pandas.DataFrame
encoded_ordin = ordin.fit_transform(X[ordin_col_names])
```

you could also use method `get_feature_names_out` (or `get_feature_names` in sklearn versions before 1.2) to get appropriate names to encoded features:

````
X.drop(oh_col_names, axis=1)
X[ohe.get_feature_names_out()] = encoded_oh

X.drop(ordin_col_names, axis=1)
X[ordin.get_feature_names_out()] = encoded_ordin
```
````